# Sign up is not an enclosing class

Tags: java, android

I have created a function Backgroundtask and instantiated to the other class but it is giving error that Signup is not an enclosing class
Instantiation:

```
BackgroundTask backgroundTask = new BackgroundTask(Signup.this);
```

Code for Backgroundtask

```
public class BackgroundTask extends AsyncTask<String,Void,String> {

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
        String urlLogin = "http://localhost/49ersense/login.php";
        String urlRegister ="http://localhost/49ersense/register.php";
        String task=params[0];
        if(task.equals("register")){
            String fullname1=params[1];
            String username1=params[2];
            String password1=params[3];
            String emailid1=params[4];
            String phone1=params[5];
            String address1=params[6];
            String userid1=params[7];

            try {
                URL url= new URL(urlRegister);
                HttpURLConnection httpURLConnection =(HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
                httpURLConnection.setRequestMethod("POST");
                httpURLConnection.setDoOutput(true);
                OutputStream outputStream= httpURLConnection.getOutputStream() ;
                OutputStreamWriter outputStreamWriter= new OutputStreamWriter(outputStream,"UTF-8");
                BufferedWriter bufferedWriter = new BufferedWriter(outputStreamWriter);
                String myData= URLEncoder.encode("fullname","UTF-8")+"="+URLEncoder.encode("fullname1","UTF-8")+"&"
                        +URLEncoder.encode("username","UTF-8")+"="+URLEncoder.encode("username1","UTF-8")+"&"
                        +URLEncoder.encode("password","UTF-8")+"="+URLEncoder.encode("password1","UTF-8")+"&"
                        +URLEncoder.encode("emailid","UTF-8")+"="+URLEncoder.encode("emailid1","UTF-8")+"&"
                        +URLEncoder.encode("phone","UTF-8")+"="+URLEncoder.encode("phone1","UTF-8")+"&"
                        +URLEncoder.encode("address","UTF-8")+"="+URLEncoder.encode("address1","UTF-8")+"&"
                        +URLEncoder.encode("userid","UTF-8")+"="+URLEncoder.encode("userid1","UTF-8");
                bufferedWriter.write(myData);
                bufferedWriter.flush();
                InputStream inputStream =httpURLConnection.getInputStream();
                inputStream.close();
            } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        if(task.equals("login")){
            String username=params[1] ;
            String password=params[2];

        }
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String aVoid) {
        super.onPostExecute(aVoid);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onProgressUpdate(Void... values) {
        super.onProgressUpdate(values);
    }
}
```

why that signup.this is showing that it is not an enclosing class and signup is the java class name where backgroundtask has been instantiated

Comment: what is that 'Signup.this' supposed to do?

Comment: What do you mean by "signup is the java class name where backgroundtask has been instantiated"? Unless Signup is an *enclosing* class for BackgroundTask, `Signup.this` won't work because there is no implicit reference for it. That sort of syntax only works in inner classes, and my guess is that `BackgroundTask` isn't an inner class of `Signup`, but we can't tell from what you've shown. Maybe you should just accept a `Signup` reference in a `BackgroundTask` constructor and retain it as a field...

Comment: @Stultuske I think it required the context.

Comment: BackgroundTask backgroundtask = new BackgroundTask(this);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't see any constructor for Context.

```
public class BackgroundTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {

    private final Context mContext;

    public BackgroundTask(final Context context) {
         mContext = context;
    }
}
```

Pass the context to the async task like this :

```
final BackgroundTask task = new BackgroundTask(getApplicationContext());
```

Pass the context according to it.

Answer (score 1):

```
Context context;
    BackgroundTask(Context ctx){
        this.context=ctx;
    }
```

I added this to my BackgroundTask class and now it works!! thanks